# Doctrine Query Builder - Search in collection

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to create fulltext search in Doctrine Query Builder. But I have here one problem.

**In Post Entity I have this**:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="posts")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *     name="posts_tags",
     *     joinColumns={
     *         @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *     },
     *     inverseJoinColumns={
     *         @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *     }
     * )
     */
    protected $tags;
```

And I'm searching in post with this code:

```
$searched = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();

$searched->select('p')
         ->from(Post::getClassName(), 'p');

$searched->where(
               $searched->expr()->like('p.title', $searched->expr()->literal('%' . $values->search . '%'))
            );
```

But now I don't know how to search in "tags" because it's collection. Can somebody put me on right journey? Thank you very much.

Comment: For clarification: Do you want to limit your search to posts that have a certain tag?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an inner join:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$posts = $qb->select('p')
    ->from(Post::getClassName(), 'p')
    ->innerJoin('p.tags', 't')
    ->where($qb->expr()->like('p.title', ':postTitle'))
    ->andWhere('t.name = :tagName')
    ->setParameter("postTitle", "%{$values->search}%")
    ->setParameter("tagName", "foobar")
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Some variable names are made up, as I don't know your exact schema, but this should get you going.